# CSS for Fade in/out Image link?

Tags: css

http://buckinghamid.com/portfolio/portfolio/

On the site above, I would like to use the effect they use on their portfolio images (I believe it was created in WP).  When you hover, the picture fades out and darkens slightly, showing a little descriptive text, as well as being a link to a new page if clicked.  When you hover off, it goes back to the full opacity image only. Can this be done using css?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: i see the code, of the website, and they are using this plugin for wordpress http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/H93KN/

```
#mainwrapper .box .simple-caption {
height: 30px;
width: 200px;
display: block;
bottom: -30px;
line-height: 25pt;
text-align: center;
 }
```